# Sharepoint 365 : Show number unread emails from Outlook 365

Tags: outlook, sharepoint-online

What do you need to into Code-Snipit in Sharepoint 365 (online) to show the number of unread mails in my Outlook 365 (online) mailbox?

Answer (score 0):

We can get the unread emails from the Inbox folder of the current user with the help of Microsoft Graph API.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=isRead ne true&$count=true
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is true. But I can't figure out how I can get the access token and where to put in the url. Do you know that?

Answer (score -1):

Displaying the number of unread emails from Outlook 365 in SharePoint 365 (online) is a common request to enhance productivity. However, it's important to note that there isn't a native feature for achieving this. To bridge this gap, you can create a custom web part in SharePoint using a code snippet. This web part will provide you with the desired functionality.

Here is a code snippet that you can use to get started:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get the number of unread emails in Outlook 365
  var unreadEmails = 0;
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$count=true",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer <YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      unreadEmails = data.count;
    }
  });

  // Display the number of unread emails in the web part
  $("#unreadEmails").text(unreadEmails);
});
</script>

<div id="unreadEmails"></div>
```

To implement this code snippet, you'll need to replace <YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN> with your actual access token obtained from the Azure portal. Once this is in place, you can embed the code in a custom web part in SharePoint 365. The resulting web part can be added to any SharePoint page, where it will conveniently display the count of unread emails in your Outlook 365 mailbox.

Keep in mind that this is a foundational example, and you can further customize it to meet your specific requirements. You have the flexibility to style the display of the unread email count or expand the web part's features. Customizing the code allows you to create a seamless integration between SharePoint and Outlook 365 for improved user experience and productivity.